# Using JSON on url_address

Tags: python, json, url

I have used urllib.request.urlopen('....') and received the following result:

```
url_address = urllib.request.urlopen('....')
data = json.loads(url_address.read())

b'137696,1664,48095225\n129907,90,5354763\n150314,85,3316136\n292634,84,3174504\n248365,87,4088707\n365908,79,1849614\n262326,67,550318\n503762,69,705908\n44356,99,13065267\n288934,70,781133\n120130,85,3260661\n355951,64,434948\n215543,66,536087\n203090,70,737697\n41563,82,2479872\n224644,64,436468\n184570,61,302395\n285002,62,361824\n285071,53,147674\n101071,85,3512315\n50733,82,2486026\n171716,52,129734\n334208,47,75129\n146628,61,308045\n179311,6\n145128,11\n51986,175\n-1,-1\n-1,-1\n27919,157\n-1,-1\n135580,1\n-1,-1\n'
```

I have tried to use JSON in order to seperate it where commas however I got the following error:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 7 (char 6)
```

Is there a way I can get an array result of like:

```
137696

1664

48095225
```

and so on.

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean, you used JSON? That result you're showing isn't JSON.

Comment: That output is mostly just a CSV file. You could probably parse it with Python's CSV parser.

Comment: Json error on column is the first comma because you lack the leading [ and trailing ] in your response data. Also the line breaks need commas too.

Comment: thats the data i get from the api its not something in my control (unless I didnt understand you)

Comment: that's not JSON data, most probably it's CSV. use a csv parser or treat it like a string and parse it with your own code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the result of API is not formatted in JSON (more like CSV). so if the data always gonna be like that you can treat it like a string and parse it with:

```
//result1 is an array
//result2 is a string
data = ''
a = b'137696,1664,48095225\n129907,90,5354763\n150314,85,3316136\n292634,84,3174504\n248365,87,4088707\n365908,79,1849614\n262326,67,550318\n503762,69,705908\n44356,99,13065267\n288934,70,781133\n120130,85,3260661\n355951,64,434948\n215543,66,536087\n203090,70,737697\n41563,82,2479872\n224644,64,436468\n184570,61,302395\n285002,62,361824\n285071,53,147674\n101071,85,3512315\n50733,82,2486026\n171716,52,129734\n334208,47,75129\n146628,61,308045\n179311,6\n145128,11\n51986,175\n-1,-1\n-1,-1\n27919,157\n-1,-1\n135580,1\n-1,-1\n'
data += str(a)
data = data[1:]
result1 = data.replace('\n',',').split(',')
result2 = ''
for r in result1:
    result2 += r + '\n'
```

Comment: any recommendation how to remove the letter 'b' from the result i get? It says its byte type.